# AutoMapper flattening of nested mappings asks for a custom resolver

Tags: .net, mapping, automapper, dto

I'm somewhat new to AutoMapper and wanted to map a POCO-ish object to a perhaps more complex DTO, the latter tries to be a representation of a [Google Books API's Volume](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/reference/volumes) resource:

**Book.cs**

```
public class Book
{
    public string Isbn10 { get; set; }
    public string Isbn13 { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    public DateTime Publication { get; set; }
    public int Pages { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool InStock { get; set; }
}
```

**BookDto.cs**

```
public class BookDto
{
    public string Kind { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public VolumeInfo VolumeInfo { get; set; }
}

public class VolumeInfo
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<string> Authors { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    public string PublishedDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
    public List<IndustryIdentifier> IndustryIdentifiers { get; set; }
}

public class IndustryIdentifier
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
}
```

So according to the [documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Nested-mappings) *we could simply flatten* the nested type:

**AutoMapperConfigurator.cs**

```
public static class AutoMapperConfigurator
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Book, BookDto>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Id, options => options.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Kind, options => options.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dto => dto.VolumeInfo.Title, options => options.MapFrom(book => book.Title))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.VolumeInfo.Authors, options => options.MapFrom(book => book.Author.ToArray()))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.VolumeInfo.Publisher, options => options.MapFrom(book => book.Publisher))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.VolumeInfo.PublishedDate, options => options.MapFrom(book => book.Publication))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.VolumeInfo.Description, options => options.MapFrom(book => book.Description))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.VolumeInfo.PageCount, options => options.MapFrom(book => book.Pages))
            ;
    }
}
```

But unfortunately when running the `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` Test I'm getting the following error:

> System.ArgumentException : Expression 'dto => dto.VolumeInfo.Title'
>   must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's
>   properties. Use a custom resolver on the child type or the AfterMap
>   option instead. Parameter name: lambdaExpression

So now following that advice trying with AfterMap:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfigurator
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Book, BookDto>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Id, options => options.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Kind, options => options.Ignore())
            .AfterMap((book, bookDto) => bookDto.VolumeInfo = new VolumeInfo 
                { 
                    Title = book.Title,
                    Authors = new List<string>(){ book.Author },
                    Publisher = book.Publisher,
                    PublishedDate = book.Publication.ToShortDateString(),
                    Description = book.Description,
                    PageCount = book.Pages
                });
    }
}
```

When running the test again I'm now getting this message:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below. Add a
>   custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver,  or modify
>   the source/destination type Book -> BookDto (Destination member list)
>   Dotnet.Samples.AutoMapper.Book -> Dotnet.Samples.AutoMapper.BookDto
>   (Destination member list) VolumeInfo

Should I create additional mappings between the nested classes? Any guidance will be sincerely appreciated, thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I've done something similar before using .ForMember with an internal mapping for the VolumnInfo mapping:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfigurator
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Book, VolumeInfo>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Authors, options => options.MapFrom(book => book.Author.Split(',')))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.PublishedDate, options => options.MapFrom(book => book.Publication))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.PageCount, options => options.MapFrom(book => book.Pages))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.IndustryIdentifiers, options => options.Ignore());

        Mapper.CreateMap<Book, BookDto>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Id, options => options.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Kind, options => options.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dto => dto.VolumeInfo, options => options.MapFrom(book => Mapper.Map<Book, VolumeInfo>(book)));
    }
}
```

Here are a couple of unit tests that verify the functionality:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MappingTests
{
    [Test]
    public void AutoMapper_Configuration_IsValid()
    {
        AutoMapperConfigurator.Configure();
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }

    [Test]
    public void AutoMapper_MapsAsExpected()
    {
        AutoMapperConfigurator.Configure();
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        var book = new Book
            {
                Author = "Castle,Rocks",
                Description = "Awesome TV",
                InStock = true,
                Isbn10 = "0123456789",
                Isbn13 = "0123456789012",
                Pages = 321321,
                Publication = new DateTime(2012, 11, 01),
                Publisher = "Unknown",
                Title = "Why I Rock"
            };

        var dto = Mapper.Map<Book, BookDto>(book);

        Assert.That(dto.Id, Is.Null);
        Assert.That(dto.Kind, Is.Null);
        Assert.That(dto.VolumeInfo, Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(dto.VolumeInfo.Authors, Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(dto.VolumeInfo.Authors.Count, Is.EqualTo(2));
        Assert.That(dto.VolumeInfo.Authors[0], Is.EqualTo("Castle"));
        Assert.That(dto.VolumeInfo.Authors[1], Is.EqualTo("Rocks"));
        Assert.That(dto.VolumeInfo.Description, Is.EqualTo("Awesome TV"));
        Assert.That(dto.VolumeInfo.IndustryIdentifiers, Is.Null);
        Assert.That(dto.VolumeInfo.PageCount, Is.EqualTo(321321));
        Assert.That(dto.VolumeInfo.PublishedDate, Is.EqualTo(new DateTime(2012, 11, 01).ToString()));
        Assert.That(dto.VolumeInfo.Publisher, Is.EqualTo("Unknown"));
        Assert.That(dto.VolumeInfo.Title, Is.EqualTo("Why I Rock"));
    }
}
```

Comment: It works - thanks much! So basically I must have one mapping for each nesting - e.g. for `IndustryIdentifiers` I should go `Mapper.CreateMap<VolumeInfo, IndustryIdentifier>()` as well

Comment: You haven't specified where you get Type and Identifier from, but I suspect it'll be from `Book`. Therefore you will need something like `Mapper.CreateMap<Book, IndustryIdentifier>()`, and update the `.ForMember(dto => dto.IndustryIdentifiers...` mapping above to call `options.MapFrom(book => Mapper.Map<Book, IndustryIdentifiers>(book))`. That's not exactly right as you've defined it as a list, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I did and therefore having the problem you mention with the List.

Comment: If you show me where you want to get `Type` and `Identifier` from, I'll take a look at the configuration

Comment: According to the docs, e.g. for `Isbn13` `Type` should be "ISBN_13" and `Identifier` would be the number itself. I guess I´ve solved it, here´s the snippet if you want to take a look: https://raw.github.com/nanotaboada/dotnet/master/Dotnet.Samples.AutoMapper/Dotnet.Samples.AutoMapper/src/AutoMapperConfigurator.cs

Comment: Cool. Looks like you might want to change the mapping for `volumeInfo.IndustryIdentifiers` from a `options.UseValue` to a `options.MapFrom` otherwise the mapping will always create an empty list. But looks good.